# Modify an array in windows batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need to concatenate a string after modifying an array in a windows batch script.

Can anyone point what am I doing wrong here?

For this I wrote batch script `script_tests.bat`. After executing the script `script_tests.bat` should be produce `Tags="@TestCaseKey=2,@TestCaseKey=5"`

Invoke script with parameters: `script_tests.bat "testcaseIds=[2,5]"`

```
:: script_tests.bat

:parse
IF "%~1"=="" GOTO endParse
ECHO "%~1" | FIND /I "=" && SET "%~1"
SHIFT /1
GOTO parse
:endParse

set testcaseIds=%testcaseIds:[=%
set testcaseIds=%testcaseIds:]=%

FOR %%A IN (%testcaseIds%) DO (
    set Tags=@TestCaseKey=%%A,%Tags%
)
echo %Tags%
```

Comment: `DelayedExpansion` is required with `!` expensaion to modify a variable during a for loop if it references itself or if the new value is referenced within the for loop. Alternately, `Call Set` can be used in conjunction with doubling `%` symbols of the variable to be referenced. IE: `Call  set "Tags=@TestCaseKey=%%A,%%Tags%%"`

Comment: `FOR /f "tokens=1,2 delims=[,]" %%A IN ("%testcaseids%") DO set Tags=@TestCaseKey=%%A,%%B` removes the need for delayed expansion *and* makes it unnecessary to remove the `[ ]`.

Comment: Use this line instead of your FOR: `set Tags="@TestCaseKey=%testcaseIds:,=,@TestCaseKey=%"` This works with _any number_ of subscripts. Note: you are _not_ working with [arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10167990/778560) here...